# How to use Aws SQS as event source and invoke different Lamda function based on event Attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

guys need small help, I have a use case, where I want to set up a communication service. 
using  SQS, SQs is going to receive a different type of events to be communicated. Now we have a single lambda function which does a single communication. let's say one email Lambda, Slack lambda, etc.

how I can invoke different lambda based on queue attributes. I was planning to use SQS as an event source  and something kind of this architecture [link to sample architeture](https://dzone.com/articles/amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source-to-aws-lambda-a-deep)

here in the above, we can handle rate limiting and concurrency at the lambda service level 
simplified works if event type is A invoke Lambda A if the event type is B invoke a lambda B
and both events are in same SQS

all suggestions are welcome

Comment: what about just use 2 queues?

Comment: it is needed a master queue for communication service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is a SQS message can only be read by one service at a time. When it is being read, it is invisible to anyone else. You can only have one Lambda consumer and there isn't any partitioning or routing in SQS besides setting up another SQS topic. Multiple consumers are implemented Kensis or AWS MSK (Kafka)

What you are trying to accomplish is called a fan out. This is a common cloud architecture. What you probably want to do is publish initially to SNS. Then with SNS you can filter and route to multiple SQS topics for each of the message types and each SQS topic would then be consumed by it's own Lambda.

Check out a tutorial here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-common-scenarios.html